# Does RSS readers read a XML on localhost?

Tags: php, xml, rss, localhost, feed

I am trying to use RSS on my webpage, but this one is on localhost. I have created an XML which is shown on screen when I type on the URL `localhost/rss`, so it works well.

I also wrote next line in my `index.php`, to let browsers know that my page has RSS feed:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php echo ROOT; ?>pages/rss.php" />
```

The problem is that in RSS Reader Netvibes (for example), when I type on feed address/URL autodetection box my URLs, I get next messages:

- If I type `http://localhost` or `127.0.0.1`: No feed was found on this page.
- If I type `http://localhost/rss` or `127.0.0.1/rss`: No feed has been found at this address (404 Not Found).

What is happening? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as the `localhost` hosting the server is the same as the reader's fetcher is running, yes.

Netvibes, however, is a hosted service. It doesn't run on your computer and has no access to your computer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then, from localhost, how could I test whether my RSS feed is working or not?

Comment: Use RSS software that runs on your computer (I'd install a local copy of feed validator and write a test script using my preferred programming language / test framework / library for RSS parsing).